# Issues finding and replacing strings in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, io

I'm rather new to PowerShell and I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to convert some statements in VBScript to Microsoft JScript. Here is my code:

```
$vbs = 'C:\infile.vbs'
$js = 'C:\outfile.js'

(Get-Content $vbs | Set-Content $js)
(Get-Content $js) |
 Foreach-Object { $_ -match "Sub " } | Foreach-Object { "$_()`n`{" } | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Sub", "function" } | Out-File $js
 Foreach-Object { $_ -match "End Sub" } | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "End Sub", "`}" } | Out-File $js
 Foreach-Object { $_ -match "Function " } | Foreach-Object { "$_()`n`{" } | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "Function", "function" } | Out-File $js
 Foreach-Object { $_ -match "End Function" } | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "End Function", "`}" } | Out-File $js
```

What I want is for my PowerShell program to take the code from the  VBScript input file `infile.vbs`, convert it, and output it to the JScript output file `outfile.js`. Here is an example of what I want it to do:

Input file:

```
Sub HelloWorld
 (Code Here)
End Sub
```

Output File:

```
function HelloWorld()
{
 (Code Here)
}
```

Something similar would happen with regard to functions. From there, I would tweak the code manually to convert it. When I run my program in PowerShell v5.1, it does not show any errors. However, when I open `outfile.js`, I see only one line:

```
False
```

So really, I have two questions. 
1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I fix this program so that it behaves how I want it to (as detailed above)?

Thanks,

Gabe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for question #2 (*How can I fix this program [...]?*):

[Kirill Pashkov's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571406/45375) offers an elegant solution based on the `switch` statement.

Note, however, that his solution:

- is predicated on `Sub <name>` / `Function <name>` statement parts *not being on the same line* as the matching `End Sub` / `End Function` parts - while this is *typically* the case, it isn't a *syntactical* requirement; e.g., `Sub Foo() WScript.Echo("hi") End Sub` - on a single line - works too.
- in line with your own solution attempt, blindly appends `()` to `Sub` / `Function` definitions, which won't work with input procedures / functions that already have parameter declarations (e.g., `Sub Foo (bar, baz)`).

The following solution:

- also works with *single-line* `Sub` / `Function` definition
- correctly preserves parameter declarations

```
Get-Content $vbs | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace '\b(?:sub|function)\s+(\w+)\s*(\(.*?\))', 'function $1$2 {' `
     -replace '\bend\s+(?:sub|function)\b', '}'
} | Out-File $js
```

The above relies heavily on [regexes (regular expressions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) to transform the input; for specifics on how regex matching results can be referred to in the `-replace` operator's replacement-string operand, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

*Caveat*: There are many other syntax differences between VBScript and JScript that your approach doesn't cover, notably that VBScript has no `return` statement and instead uses `<funcName> = ...` to return values from functions.

---

As for question #1:

> However, when I open outfile.js, I see only one line:
>   `False`
>   [...]
>   1. **Why is this happening?**

- **All but the *first* `ForEach-Object` cmdlet call run in *separate statements*, because the initial pipeline *ends* with the *first* call to `Out-File $js`.**
- The subsequent `ForEach-Object` calls each *start a new pipeline*, and since each pipeline ends with `Out-File $js`, *each* such pipeline writes to file `$js` - and thereby *overwrites* whatever the previous one wrote.
  Therefore, it is the *last* pipeline that determines the ultimate contents of file `$js`.
- A `ForEach-Object` that *starts* a pipeline receives *no input*. However, its associated script block (`{...}`) is still entered *once* in this case, with `$_` being `$null`<sup>[1]</sup>:

  - The last pipeline starts with `Foreach-Object { $_ -match "End Function" }`, so its output is the equivalent of `$null -match "End Function"`, which yields `$False`, because `-match` with a *scalar* LHS (a single input object) outputs a *Boolean* value that indicates whether a match was found or not.
  - Therefore, given that the *middle* pipeline segment (`Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "End Function", "}" }`) is an effective *no-op* (`$False` is stringified to `'False'`, and the `-replace` operator therefore finds no match to replace and passes the stringified input out unmodified), `Out-File $js` receives string `'False'` and writes just that to output file `$js`.

---

Even if you transformed your separate commands into a *single* pipeline with a single `Out-File $js` segment at the very end, your command wouldn't work, however:

Given that `Get-Content` sends the input file's lines through the pipeline *one by one*, something like `$_ -match "Sub "` will again produce a *Boolean* result - indicating whether the line at hand (`$_`) matched string `"Sub "` - and pass *that* on.

While you could turn `-match` into a *filter* by making the LHS an *array* - by enclosing it in the array-subexpression operator `@(...)`; e.g., `@($_) -match "Sub "` - that would:

- pass line that contain substring `Sub` through *as a whole*, and
- *omit* lines that don't.

In other words: This wouldn't work as intended, because:

- lines that do not contain a matching substring would be *omitted* from the output, and
- the lines that do match are reflected *in full* in `$_` in the next pipeline segment - not just the *matched part*.

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, `$_` will retain whatever value it had in the current scope, but that will only be non-`$null` if you *explicitly assigned a value to `$_`* - given that `$_` is an *automatic* variable that is normally controlled by PowerShell itself, however, doing so is ill-advised - see [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3695).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6) statement. Like so:

```
$vbs = 'C:\infile.vbs'
$js = 'C:\outfile.js'

Get-Content $vbs | ForEach-Object {
        switch -Regex ($_) {
        'Sub '{
            'function {0}(){1}{2}' -f $_.Remove($_.IndexOf('Sub '),4).Trim(),[Environment]::NewLine,'{'
        }
        'End Sub'{
            '}'
        }
        'Function ' {
            'function {0}(){1}{2}' -f $_.Remove($_.IndexOf('Function '),9).Trim(),[Environment]::NewLine,'{'
        }
        'End Function' {
            '}'
        }
        default {
            $_
        }
    }
} | Out-File $js
```

Answer (score 0):

OK there is a few things wrong with this script. 
**Foreach-Object** otherwise known as **%** is to iterate every item in a pipe.
Example is

```
@(1..10) | %{ "This is Array Item $_"}
```

This will out put 10 lines counting the array items. In you current script you are using this where a **Where-Object** also known as *?* should be.

```
@(1..10) | ?{ $_ -gt 5 }
```

This will output all numbers greater then 5.

A example of what you are kind of trying to go for is something like

```
function ConvertTo-JS([string]$InputFilePath,[string]$SaveAs){
    Get-Content $InputFilePath |
        %{$_ -replace "Sub", "function"} |
        %{$_ -replace "End Function", "}"} |
        %{$_ -replace "Function", "function"} |
        %{$_ -replace "End Function", "}" } |
        Out-File $SaveAs
}

ConvertTo-JS -InputFilePath "C:\TEST\TEST.vbs" -SaveAs "C:\TEST\TEST.JS"
```

This doesnt take into account adding a { at the beginning of a function or adding the () ether. But with the information provided hopefully that puts you on the right track.